# How do I maintain photo filters (e.g. Noir) when transferring from iPhone to iPhoto on MacBook?

Tags: photos.app, iphone

I love using my 5c photo filters but when I go to download photos into iPhoto on my MacBook Pro from my iPhone, the filters disappear. All my photos end up in color. How do I maintain the filters?

Answer (score 1):

I've asked this question at a GeniusBar in an AppleStore and also searched the web quite thoroughly on this.

Apparently, the only way to maintain the filters is with workarounds such as emailing the photos to yourself.

Background: Only the original photos (without the filter) are stored in the iPhone and iOS applies the filter every time you view the photos or use an iPhone App (like Mail) to export them. Apps from your Mac (like iPhoto) can only access the original photos.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a Macbook Pro, you can try Airdrop also to send the photos to your Macbook . This will retain the filters. This is the necessary sacrifice for constructive editing feature of iOS . Treat Airdrop/sharing as export . This is the behavior with any constructive image editing application .